# Python - Different regular/analytic functions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

To perform the derivative, I have developed the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *

xi = jnp.linspace(-3,3)

def f(x):
  a = x**3+5
  return a


g1i = jax.vmap(jax.grad(f))(xi)
g2i = jax.vmap(jax.grad(jax.grad(f)))(xi)
g3i = jax.vmap(jax.grad(jax.grad(jax.grad(f))))(xi)
plt.plot(xi,yi,  label = "f")
plt.plot(xi,g1i, label = "f'")
plt.plot(xi,g2i, label = "f''")
plt.plot(xi,g3i, label = "f'''")
plt.legend()
```

**This code works, but now I am interested in apply the following code to compute the first derivative of a Call price, with respect to the underlying asset (i.e. delta), trying with the following, but it does not works:**

```
import scipy.stats as si
import sympy as sy
import sys
xi = jnp.linspace(1,1.5)
def analytical_call(s0):
    T=1.
    q=0.
    r=0.
    k=1.
    sigma=0.4
    Kt = k*exp((q-r)*T)
    d = (log(Kt/s0)+(sigma**2)/2*T)/sigma
    result = (Kt * si.norm.cdf((d / sqrt(T)), 0.0, 1.0)  - s0 * si.norm.cdf(((d - sigma * T) / sqrt(T)), 0.0, 1.0)  ) * exp(-q * T) + exp(-q * T) * (s0 - Kt)
    return result
print(analytical_call(1))

g1i = jax.vmap(jax.grad(analytical_call))(xi)
g2i = jax.vmap(jax.grad(jax.grad(analytical_call)))(xi)
plt.plot(xi,yi,  label = "f")
plt.plot(xi,g1i, label = "f'")
plt.legend()
```

Have you some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no `delta` inside your function `analytical_call`, so it's not clear with respect to which variable you want to differentiate. Do you mean `s0` instead? Note also that you can't mix scipy.stats and sympy methods with jax.

Comment: Yes, i mean differentiate a call with respect a stream of s0, defined in the code as "xi" @joni

Comment: Scipy is used only to compute d1.. How can I solve this problem? Because I need the sensitivity of a call with respect to a stream of underlyings, using the AAD method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can't use methods outside the jax library like `scipy.stats.norm.cdf`. Use [`jax.scipy.stats`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.scipy.html#jax-scipy-stats) instead. Similarly, replace `exp` and `sqrt` with their jax equivalents `jnp.exp` and `jnp.sqrt`:

```py
from jax import jit, grad, vmap
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax.scipy.stats.norm import cdf

def analytical_call(s0):
    T, q, r, k, sigma = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4
    Kt = k*jnp.exp((q-r)*T)
    d = (jnp.log(Kt/s0)+(sigma**2)/2*T)/sigma
    result = (Kt * cdf((d / jnp.sqrt(T)), 0.0, 1.0)  - s0 * cdf(((d - sigma * T) / jnp.sqrt(T)), 0.0, 1.0)  ) * jnp.exp(-q * T) + jnp.exp(-q * T) * (s0 - Kt)
    return result

g = vmap(grad(analytical_call))
h = vmap(grad(grad(analytical_call)))
xi = jnp.linspace(1,1.5)
```

Then, you can evaluate `g(xi)` and `h(xi)`.

Comment: I have edited the question just to attach the code about what I have tried

Comment: @John_maddon Sure. However, to keep things clear, I'd recommend posting a separate question instead of editing your previous post.