# Python - Problem with differentiating with more parameters

Tags: python, numpy

If I have more than one parameters, I'm finding a way to compute the derivative with respect just one parameters (and not all the specified ones) (for the post: [Python - Different regular/analitic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594067/python-different-regular-analitic-functions))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you can use the [`argnums`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.html#jax.grad) argument of `grad` to
specify with respect to which variable (argument) you want to differentiate:

```py
deriv_sigma = vmap(grad(analytical_call_3, argnums=1))
```

Comment: So in the code after the "EDIT", in order to differentiate only just with respect to sigma, i should set: deriv_sigma = vmap(grad(analytical_call_3, argnums=1))(xi,sigma_i) ?

Comment: If you want to directly evaluate the derivative, yes. The `deriv_sigma` in my answer is a function, so you could also simply call `deriv_sigma(xi, sigma_i)` to get the results.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! And is possible recall this function "deriv_sigma", in order to differentiate it with respect to "xi" ?

Comment: Sure, it works completely similar: `deriv_sigma_xi = vmap(grad(grad(analytical_call_3, argnums=1), argnums=0)))`. Then, you can call `deriv_sigma_xi(xi, sigma_i)` in order to evaluate the function.